# Gunicorn logstash log handler

Tags: python, django, logging, logstash, gunicorn

my log config file

```
[loggers]
keys=root, logstash

[handlers]
keys=console , logstash

[formatters]
keys=generic, access

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=console

[logger_logstash]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logstash
propagate=1
qualname=logstash


[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_logstash]
class=logstash.TCPLogstashHandler
formatter=generic
args=('localhost',5959)


[formatter_generic]
format=%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
class=logging.Formatter

[formatter_access]
format=%(message)s
class=logging.Formatter
```

my command to execute

```
gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings myproject.wsgi --log-level debug --log-file=- --log-config gunicorn_log.conf
```

I am not getting any error but logstash is not receiving access logs.
This handler worked with DJango and celery but I am helpless with gunicorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[loggers]
keys=root, logstash.error, logstash.access

[handlers]
keys=console , logstash

[formatters]
keys=generic, access, json

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=console

[logger_logstash.error]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logstash
propagate=1
qualname=gunicorn.error

[logger_logstash.access]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logstash
propagate=0
qualname=gunicorn.access


[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_logstash]
class=logstash.TCPLogstashHandler
formatter=json
args=('localhost',5959)


[formatter_generic]
format=%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
class=logging.Formatter

[formatter_access]
format=%(message)s
class=logging.Formatter

[formatter_json]
class=jsonlogging.JSONFormatter
```

The above config file worked for me 
to send logs to logstash which is running under localhost:5959

Answer (score 0):

Based on [python-logstash documentation](https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash#using-with-django):

```
[handler_logstash]
class=logstash.TCPLogstashHandler
formatter=generic
host=localhost
port=5959
version=1
```

Comment: Still same problem   . there is no error on starting gunicorn but logs not received by logstash

Comment: In `handler_console` section replace `class=StreamHandler` with `class=logging.StreamHandler`

Comment: Probably `Gunicorn` need `[logger_gunicorn.access]` section